# Can I mirror the Tuleap repo?

Tags: tuleap

I would like to mirror the Tuleap repo since the main Tuleap repo  cannot be accessed through our infrastructure. I found [these instructions](https://tuleap.net/wiki/index.php?pagename=Mirror%20tuleap.net%20rpm%20repository&group_id=101), but following the instructions gives an authorization failure. Since the [instructions in the installation guide](https://tuleap.net/doc/en/installation-guide/full-installation.html) refer to a different baseurl, should/can I mirror from ci.tuleap.net/yum/tuleap/rhel/6/dev/$basearch instead of tuleap.net/file/pub/tuleap/yum/tuleap/dev/x86_64/?

Thanks for any help.

Update: I have registered on Tuleap.net and am still unable to access the repo for mirroring. Accessing the URL from a browser asks for authentication and does not accept the Tuleap.net registration credentials. Thanks for the help.

Comment: user462280 and user520559: If you are the same person, it would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](http://superuser.com/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are http://superuser.com/users/462280/user462280 and http://superuser.com/users/520559/user520559.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.  And please register your account.

Answer (score 0):

The authorization failure means that you need a valid account on Tuleap.net.  Other than that the instructions you linked to *do* work.